# Arriving at a particular value of continuous valued output by using combination of logical variables using an ML Algorithm

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, multiple-regression, continual-learning

I have a black-box circuit problem, which consists of 40 switches and some circuitry elated to that which is unknown. Their states can either be On/Off. I can measure the output which consists of two continuous variables, where Output-1 can vary between 0 and 600 and Output-2 can vary between 1 and infinity. Task is to find the combination of the switches which can give some fixed values of output variables or atleast closer values(For example, Output-1 should be 79 and Output-2 should be 167)  . I am asked to model this as a machine learning algorithm.
Also as this is a circuit, these switches need to be in continuous learning and changing state(on/off) mode to maintain output at/or closer to desired values.
As far my ML knowledge goes, if I consider the 40 switches as logical input variables and transform them into numerical with values either 0 or 1 and run linear regression, I can get a model which can predict continuous output.
Is there a way to model the above problem as machine learning algorithm? If so can someone give some starter ideas and point me in a direction.